# Bootstrap navigation menu questions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and I am just exploring it by just reading online tutorials and documentation.  I just want to create a small POC just to understand it.

**First Question**

Please see my screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the flyout menu in the link is aligning to the left.  Is there a way to have this flyout to the right?  I tried putting pull-right classes but to no avail.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0xj3g6s/2/)

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <
```

**Second Question**

I saw from my reading that Bootstrap does not support multi level dropdown because of usability issues.  I just would like to as how to workaround this, suppose I have a top level Departments link

```
+ Departments
  - Finance
    - Billing
    - Accounting
  - Engineering
    - IT
    - General Service
```

I would like to indent the Billing/Accounting/IT/General Service and keep the Finance and Engineering department from being clickable. I do see some workaround that was able to support multi-level dropdown but since it is bootstrap recommendation so I try to follow it as much. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Mark. Was Christina's lengthy answer below of any help? It seems still unreplied to.

Comment: (With regret, downvoted - see above. Please be willing to reply and interact here - we rely on goodwill as well as gamification to keep answers rolling in. Thanks for considering the matter).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to look around for a multi-level click menu built on Bootstrap 3.x. Here's one http://jsbin.com/pavopa/1/edit, I copied it over from a Bootply. It needs CSS work. You may find others that are more finished. Don't use hovers or solutions that involve hovers. Screen size does not mean that it's a mobile device.

If you are using a `navbar-right`, the dropdown-menu aligns on the right and flyout the opposite, this is supposed to work that way, if you use `navbar-left` the dropdown-menu it is aligned on the left. So changing that would involve going into the Bootstrap CSS and adjusting it in the min-width where it occurs. It's also not a good idea as the last item and others, depending on the width, could go off screen and people won't be able use it.

Bootstrap's components don't detect edge of viewport automatically, most menu systems don't.

The way the Bootstrap navigation works, as with nearly all click navigation systems:

```
+ Departments : this is NOT a link
  + Finance : this NOT a link
    - Billing
    - Accounting
```

Anything that you want to show as a drop down, cannot be a link and a toggle at the same time unless you go against normal UX and make the text a link and the arrow the toggle.

If you have information for the "Finance" section make that your first page, such as:

```
+ Departments : Not a link
  + Finance : Not a link
    - Finance Overview
    - Billing
    - Accounting
```